# How to make apps not start up automatically on iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, startup, multitasking, ios

It seems that even when I restart my iPhone, some apps will send me notifications... so how do I make them not run by itself? (kind of like making it not in the Start Up folder on Windows 7).

The reason is that Pokemon Go is eating up a lot of RAM, and with some apps starting up and/or running in the background, it causes the Pokemon Go to run very slowly sometimes, so I would like to limit the running of other apps.  (mine is iPhone 6 Plus, and I think it has 1GB of RAM. It may be that iPhone 6S Plus has 2GB of RAM and won't have this issue).

Answer (score 1):

You might try turning off Background App Refresh.

Settings > General > Background App Refresh > Switch to OFF